# Why do I get memory errors when mmap()'ing a JPG file?

Tags: c++, file-io, mmap, arrays

I have the following section of code:

```
char*
Sender::PrepareData(char* filename, unsigned long long int bytesToTransfer)
{
    int fd, pagesize;
    char *data;

    ifstream file(filename, ios::binary | ios::ate);
    int size = file.tellg();
    cout << "File Size: " << size << endl;

    if(size < bytesToTransfer)
        {cout << "File smaller than specified number of bytes {" << bytesToTransfer << "} to transfer -- Exiting!\n"; exit(1);}

    fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

    cout << "File Open: " << filename << endl;

    pagesize = getpagesize();
    cout << "Pagesize: " << pagesize << endl;

    data = static_cast<char*>(mmap((caddr_t)0, bytesToTransfer, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0));
    if (*data == -1) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

    return data;
}
```

This seemingly works fine for text and .deb files - however, when trying with a ~3MB image file (.jpg), I get memory errors:

```
File Size: 3333840
File Open: t1.jpg
Pagesize: 4096
Memory error[Inferior 1 (process 3293) exited with code 02]
```

Am I using `mmap()` wrong? I'm trying to write a simple wrapper that will take any type of file and return a char* containing the specified number of bytes.

Comment: How does `ostream << char*` know how many bytes to write? Surely there is some important information lost .. also, why does `*data == -1` mean there is a "Memory Error"?

Comment: This works fine with a 180MB+ .txt file

Comment: I was just going based off the man page: `On error, the value MAP_FAILED (that is, (void *) -1)` -- But thanks to you both. I think checking `data==MAP_FAILED` has fixed my current issue. If someone will post an official answer, I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be checking just `data == -1` (or, even better, `MAP_FAILED`) and *not* `*data == -1` (dereferencing via `*` is wrong here).

The reason your code fails is because the first byte of every JPEG file is `FF` in hex or -1 in signed decimal.

For more detail on JPEG, Google for "JPEG file format." For example, search for "SOI" on [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/format/jpeg/egff.htm).

Comment: "The reason your code fails is because the first byte of every JPEG file is FF in hex or -1 in signed decimal." -- this is the kind of tidbits I come to Stackoverflow for! Very interesting :)